# Java - Accept Map as parameter in class

Tags: java

Sorry, im not familiar with generics, i can create a generic class like the following:

```
public class InfoField <T, U> {

}
```

The class above can accept values like:

```
<String, User>
<String, String>
<Set<UserGroup>, User>
```

But can i have class that accept map object as value? something like

```
<Map<String, String>, String>

public class InfoFieldMap <Map<T,U>, K> {

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works as you original had it:

```
class InfoField <T, U> {
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        //Example InfoField declaration
        InfoField<Map<String,String>, String> test;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that you can have a *Map* as the *key* of another *Map* as you declared in your `InfoFieldMap` class. see this simple example: [map-in-java-with-example](http://beginnersbook.com/2013/12/hashmap-in-java-with-example/)

Your declation of `InfoFieldMap` class should be:

```
public class InfoFieldMap <K, Map<K,V>> {

}
```

Where **K** is *key* field of the *Map* and **V** is the *value* of the *Map*. **V** can be a *Map* or another collection.

Comment: A Map can be used as key in another Map, at least from a technical perspective. For instance java.util.HashMap differentiates its keys by their hashcodes. Therefore anything that implements hashCode method correctly would work. But the question remains whether it is useful. There are cases where a simple 1:1 mapping is not what you want. In this situation a multivalued map might be the way to go,

Answer (score 0):

I believe you've to do something like this

```
  public class InfoFieldMap < Z extends Map<K,V>, K, V>
```